# Creating a custom scheduler using spring quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have a requirement to create a custom scheduler. I would like all the parameters defining the frequency that my jobs will run to be stored in db tables. This would allow my customers to change the frequency etc via a nice little webapp (webapp is a different application to my main one).

I know using quartz you can define all your job triggers programatically but is that just at start time? How would it work if my customer logs on a changes the schedule in the webapp. Am I able to re-define a job trigger in the original app by checking for changes periodially?

Does anyone know of any nice examples of this?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have bunch of methods in Scheduler interface. JavaDoc [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html).

Replace already scheduled job with :

- Add a new job with replace=true in [addJob method](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#addJob%28org.quartz.JobDetail,%20boolean%29)

  OR

  1. Deleting an existing job ( method: deletejob )
  2. And then adding a new job with modified details ( addjob)

Replace already scheduled triggers with

- [rescheduleJob](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#rescheduleJob%28org.quartz.TriggerKey,%20org.quartz.Trigger%29) ( If jobdetail associated with previous trigger is same for new trigger too )

  OR
- [unscheduleJob](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#unscheduleJob%28org.quartz.TriggerKey%29) followed by [scheduleJob](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#scheduleJob%28org.quartz.JobDetail,%20org.quartz.Trigger%29)

Answer (score 0):

If used with spring you can use `spring.quartz.overwrite-existing-jobs=true`