# How to rename job class for persistent Quartz Jobs?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a test quartz job like this one.

```
package com.example.spring.quartz.basic;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobDataMap;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class ExampleJob implements Job
{
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
    {
        JobDataMap map = context.getMergedJobDataMap();
        String timeout = (String)map.get("timeout");

        System.out.println("ExampleJob.execute() " + timeout);
    }
}
```

This job is persistent so it is written to the database, and it seems that Quartz writes the full qualified job class name `com.example.spring.quartz.basic.ExampleJob` to the database.

So if refactor rename the `ExampleJob` to `ExampleJob2` I end up with the exception below because quartz looks for ExampleJob and gets a class not found exception.

**Question: Is there some trick, or pattern I can use to be able to safely rename my job classes 
without causing existing job definitions to break?**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'quartzScheduler'; nested exception is org.springframework.scheduling.SchedulingException: Could not start Quartz Scheduler; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: com.example.spring.quartz.basic.ExampleJob [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.spring.quartz.basic.ExampleJob]]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:339)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:945)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.example.spring.quartz.transactional.QuartzExampleJobMain.main(QuartzExampleJobMain.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.scheduling.SchedulingException: Could not start Quartz Scheduler; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: com.example.spring.quartz.basic.ExampleJob [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.spring.quartz.basic.ExampleJob]]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.start(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:715)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:167)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: com.example.spring.quartz.basic.ExampleJob [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.spring.quartz.basic.ExampleJob]]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:683)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:526)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:143)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.startScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:649)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.start(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:712)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: com.example.spring.quartz.basic.ExampleJob [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.spring.quartz.basic.ExampleJob]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1524)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverMisfiredJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:968)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:855)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$1.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:827)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$46.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3764)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3798)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3760)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:823)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:681)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.spring.quartz.basic.ExampleJob
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1610)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1481)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1331)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate.getObjectFromBlob(PostgreSQLDelegate.java:103)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1764)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1520)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice problem to encounter with.

> Is there some trick

Yes, the trick is to redefine your job with new details.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499824/creating-a-custom-scheduler-using-spring-quartz/17500135#17500135) for howto.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Sinchan's answer:

If you have enough data to recreate the jobs (i.e. with expiration date already on file, email a reminder to employees 30 days before their license expires), write a utility to unschedule/delete all existing jobs of that type and recreate them with the new type.

Otherwise:

1. After renaming the class, create an empty `ExampleJob` class which `extends ExampleJob2`.  This should allow Quartz to read in the existing tasks.
2. Create a utility program that reads in each `ExampleJob`, immediately schedules a corresponding `ExampleJob2` with the same properties, and deletes the `ExampleJob`.
3. At this point, you should be able to remove the `ExampleJob` class.